# testing logging in function of sorcery using rspec in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, sorcery

i have added `include Sorcery::TestHelpers::Rails` inside sorcery.rb
my controller spec looks like

```
describe "success" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @attr = { :username => @user.username, :password => @user.password }
  end
  it "should sign the user in" do
    post :create, :session => @attr
    # controller.current_user.should == @user
    controller.should be_logged_in
  end
end
```

my controller looks like

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = login(params[:username], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
    if user
      redirect_back_or_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password was invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

i have User model migrated to my test environment, when i run the test it always ends up saying not logged in.

Comment: seems like the sorcery methods are not getting called inside rspec. any ideas appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `params[:session]` into the method from your test, but in the action you're referencing `params[:username]` and `params[:password]`.